# How to create two flask apps in pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I am using pythonanywhere.com to host my Python. app1 is successfully running but I am getting a 404 error when I call app2 . How do I create two applications?

```
import sys

project_one = '/Projects/One'
if project_one not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_one] + sys.path

from one import app1 as application

project_two = '/Projects/Two'
if project_two not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_two] + sys.path

from two import app2 as new_application
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host multiple web apps, you need to upgrade your account and add more web apps to it, then deploy each web app on the Web page separately.